# How to plot density functions with different length in R

Tags: r, plot, bayesian

I want to plot three different functions, where two of them are continous and only one is discrete. This is how I generate the three of them:

Packages I am using:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(MCMCpack)
library(plotfunctions)
```

```
X=rpois(20,20) #data generation
alpha=sum(X)+64
theta=seq(0,30,by=0.01)

#Priori
n=length(X)
priori=dgamma(theta,64,4)

#Likelihood
theta1=seq(0,30)
likelihood=dpois(X,theta)

#Posteriori

posteriori=dgamma(theta,shape = alpha, rate = n+4)
```

This is the plot I am using:

```
plot(theta,priori,type="l",col="black",ylim = c(0,0.5),xlab = expression(paste(theta)),ylab = "Density")
add_bars(theta,likelihood)
lines(theta,posteriori,type="l",col="green")
legend(21,0.5,legend=c("Priori","Likelihood","Posteriori"),col = c("black","red","green"),lty = 1:3,bty="n")
```

When I try to run it, I get the follwing message:

> Error in add_bars(theta, likelihood) : Different lengths of x and y.

How can I include the likelihood density within the plot?

Comment: This works fine for me and does not return any error.

Comment: the error message doesnt match your code, `verosimilitud` is undefined

Comment: also [what is this](https://github.com/cran/plotfunctions/blob/master/R/plot.R#L91:L93)

Comment: The error that I get is caused by plottting likelihood. I updated the error message

Comment: @rawr, can you be more specific? I don't understand what you're talking about

Comment: @RonakShah The problem is that Gamma distribution belongs to continous probability distribution and Poisson distribution is a discrete probability distribution. That's why I cannot plot it (likelihood, wich is a Poisson distribution) like a line. To be correct, is has to be plotted using a bar plot combined with the plot of both gamma distribution (priori and posteriori)